# How to trace which image is currently seen in my Uiscrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, offset

I am new to iOS.
I am working on `UIScrollView` based application. I have 3 images in `UIScrollView`.
I have 2 `UIButton`s which have `selector method` for Facebook and Twitter sharing. 
I want to share image which is currently seen in `UIScrollView` to `Facebook` & `Twitter`.
I am stuck at extracting image at current scroll point.
After Googling I think something like `UIPageController` is the solution for me.
But I do not have any idea about how to implement it.

Please help me sort it out. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a page controller (basically, you allow the user to end its scrolling on specific index).
Or when the user touches a button, you can retrieve the contentOffset of the scrollView and compare this value with the origin of the frame your images.

Assume, you created your images with these frames:

```
image1.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,250);
image2.frame = CGRectMake(0,250,320,250);
image3.frame = CGRectMake(0,500,320,250);
```

Now when you get the action:

```
-(IBAction)share:(id)sender {
    CGPoint offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
    if (offset.y < 250) {
        //First image selected
    }else if (offset.y > 500) {
        //Third image selected
    } else {
       //Second image selected 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have multiple options here, this is really a design question.

An easy (but also not very elegant) approach would be to fetch the current offset of the scroll view using its `contentOffset` property (depending on whether your scroll view scrolls horizontically or vertically, you have ease to use the x or y value of the `contentOffset`).

Next, you get the position values from your image views (again either `myImageView.frame.origin.x` or `myImageView.frame.origin.y`) and you can then calculate which of the image views is currently in the offset of the scroll view.